# DevTools detect working css / hide invalid css

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-devtools

Here I'm using Google Chrome Developer Tools to check others website's css.

By default, DevTools display all elements css rule, whether that rule working or not. Some may have been inherited or commented, but they all listed on the "Styles" panel.

The question is, how could I remove rules those had been commented or inherited, just keep rules in working?

See bellow: [Example Picture Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGq43.png)

I've searched for a while, but didn't find any topic about this.

Any help is welcome, thanks!

Comment: You can go to the tab "computed" to se the styles applied to a element

Comment: Thanks, it's working! Thank you for reply!

Answer (score 1):

Check out the "Computed" tab, to the right of "Styles".
It shows a list of styles that are valid and in use.
Select "show all" to see a full list, even ones not specifically declared.

Comment: Thanks!!! That work! You save my time!